# Solid of revolution,$ y$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

The curve of a parabola $y=3x^2, 0≤x≤2$, rotates around the $y$-axis. Calculate the volume of the vase formed ?

Sorry for the awkward translation. Really need help with this on even though I know it should be easy! It's just been so long since I last messed with these things.

Really need this, I'm not attending to the exams so I must return every single problem or I'll get $1/5$ grade instead of $3/5$. This is the last one.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some indication of what your done so far so people have a better idea of your background and can then tailor their answers to your level. It will also demonstrate to people that you aren't just trying to get someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: What techniques do you know to find a volume of revolution?

Comment: I've been trying to integrate the crosscut of it with area{0,12}(A(y) dy but I'm kind of lost with this. I know the formula for x-axis is V=pi*area(f(x)^2 dx.

Comment: I am  puzzled by the description of the region that is being rotated. Is the condition really $0\le x\le 2y$?

Comment: Whoops, its 0≤x≤2, not 2y.

Comment: You can find the formulas for surfaces of revolution on wikipedia. Good for review if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write the function in terms of $y$, currently it is in terms of $x$, but you need to revolve around the $y$ axis.

Then, rewrite the bounds in terms of two $y$ values. Finally, use the formula

$$V=\pi\int \limits_{y_1}^{y_2} f(y)^2 dy$$